# I just upgraded to Lightroom CC from 5.7 and now all my photos are messed up

Tags: lightroom

I just upgraded to Lightroom CC from 5.7 and all my photos look like this now:
[image: messed up photo]

The problem is in develop mode only. They look fine in the grid and loupe views and when I export them as well. I can also edit them normally, although it's hard to see what I'm doing. Also, all my photos are taking a lot longer to load now as well. What gives? I've restarted my computer but it didn't help.
Thanks!

Comment: try disabling hardware acceleration in preferences

Comment: That fixes it! I'd like to use the hardware acceleration though. I updated to the latest drivers but it doesn't help. Is there anything I can do to make it work with hardware acceleration on? Thanks!

Comment: What vga you have?

Comment: Intel HD Graphics 4000 according to Device Manager. But it has NVIDIA drivers that are kept up to date by NVIDIA's GeForce Experience app.

Comment: If you r on a notebook you must set in Nvidia control panel to use nvida gpu with Lr and Ps, ecc, ecc, . If you don't do this, any application use the default integrated vga card (the intel one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely due to problems with your graphics card driver. Try disabling the hardware acceleration.

Set the option to off and restart LR to see if that fixes the issue. If yes, you might try to see how far you can go with the custom settings by slowly re-enabling stuff until the issue reappears.

[image: Preferences]